# ZSH: Stripping path, filename and extension from a list of files for piping a command

Tags: zsh, imagemagick

The syntax for the command [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) in [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) is

```
convert source_filename.ext1  destination_filename.ext2
```

I would like to use zsh to feed it with files in a folder `path_to_source` and output the result (files with same name, but with a **different extension**) under the folder `path_to_destination`.

I believe I can use `find` and `xargs` for this, but I didn't come up with anything that worked. Also I presume that ZSH may have some builtins that are useful for this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** As far as I know, `convert` does not have a native way of handling a batch of files, so I need to feed the files one by one. In either case, I'm interested in solving the problem of feeding a command file by file with these arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for x in /path/to/source/**/*.ext1; do convert $x ${x:r}.ext2 done
```

The `r` in `${x:r}` is a [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers). There's a short form of `for` that saves a few characters.

```
for x (/path/to/source/**/*.ext1) convert $x ${x:r}.ext2
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with:

```
cd path_to_source
find . | sed 's/.ext1$//' | xargs convert {}.ext1 ../path_to_destination/{}.ext2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can batch process your files with `mogrify` and convert from one format to another using the `-path` option (as of `imagemagick v6.2.0`) to specify a different directory in which to output the processed images:

```
mogrify -path /path/to/dest_filename -format ext2 /path/to/source_filename/*.ext1
```

so e.g.

```
mogrify -path /home/myjpgs -format jpg /media/images/*.png
```

will convert all `.png` images in the `/media/images` directory to `jpg` keeping the same filename (only the extension changes) and saving the resulting images to `/home/myjpgs`