# Shell script to convert PDF to images and save in sub-folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a bash scrip that uses Imagemagick to convert PDF's to images in a given directory (passed as an argument), and then save that conversion into a sub-folder of that directory. I have a script the works perfectly fine for converting and saving into the same directory, but when I try to add the path I'd like to converted files to be saved at the script breaks.

Here's what I have so far that works:

```
DIR="$@"
EXT="*.pdf"

mkdir -p "${DIR}images"
shopt -s nullglob
for pdffile in "$DIR"*.pdf; do
    convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 90 -trim "${pdffile}" "${pdffile%.*}".jpeg
done
```

Here's what I've tried for saving into a sub-folder. If I add "images/..." however to the last argument in converted like so:

```
DIR="$@"
EXT="*.pdf"

mkdir -p "${DIR}images"
shopt -s nullglob
for pdffile in "$DIR"*.pdf; do
    convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 90 -trim "${pdffile}" "images/${pdffile%.*}".jpeg
done
```

This is what happens when I execute the script:

```
$ ls foo
bar.pdf  baz.pdf  biz.pdf
$ ./pdf-to-img.sh foo/
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `images/foo/bar.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `images/foo/baz.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `images/foo/biz.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember that `${pdffile%.*}` will include the `DIR` prefix. Also please [edit] your question to show exactly how you're running the script - and the complete (unedited) error.

Comment: Question has been edited to reflect the complete error

Comment: So the error should be obvious now, no? you need to remove the `DIR` component (in this case `foo`) from `${pdffile%.*}"`

Comment: I've tried that, but unfortunately I'm still getting that error.

Comment: You don't need a loop, you can do this [in one go if you use `mogrify` with `-path`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220549/22142)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
DIR="$@"
EXT="*.pdf"

mkdir -p "${DIR}/images"
shopt -s nullglob
for pdffile in "$DIR"*.pdf; do
    convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 90 -trim "${pdffile}" "$(dirname "${pdffile}")/images/$(basename "${pdffile%.*}").jpeg"
done
```

It should transform this path `images/foo/bar.jpeg`, which causes error, to this `foo/images/bar.jpeg`

**Explanation:**

You have value like this `"foo/bar.pdf"` in the `${pdffile}` variable

`dirname ${pdffile}` - remove last non-slash component from path, leaving this: `"foo"`

`basename ${pdffile%}` - conversely, remove all except file name, leaving this: `"bar.pdf"`

Finally, inserting subdirctory name `$images` in between this parts and get needed path for storing images - `foo/images/bar.jpeg`.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. So the `$` in `$images` was typo and not actually in my script, so it's just `images/`; sorry about that :( That being said however, I tried your  other recommendation but that didn't work. The folder name has spaces in it, and it looks like the spaces are causing a problem. Lets say the real folder name is "PDFs For Courts", the error message I'm getting is:

`basename: extra operand ‘For’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined ``../../data/entities
.
.
Courts//.jpeg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.`

Comment: If images not variable, dollar sign should be removed. And I add double quotas for spaces handling. Try this string: $(dirname "${pdffile}")/images/$(basename "${pdffile%.*}").jpeg If this will work, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Outer quotas for whole string don't needed in this case, don't add them.

Comment: I have added whole corrected code to my answer.

Comment: I had to add outer quotes for on the output part so that it looked like:
`"$(dirname "${pdffile}")/images/$(basename "${pdffile%.*}").jpeg"` in order to get it to work (otherwise it still choked on the spaces in the directory name) but it works! Thank you.

Comment: I think again and grasp that it is right, outer quotes are needed too in this case. I have edited answer.

Comment: Hey this convert command is taking too long to convert 1 pdf of 100 page to jpg @MiniMax